# Kotlin - Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'Editable!' and 'String' when comparing string

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

So, Just started working with **Kotlin** in **Android Studio 3.0 Canary 7** and I was carrying out a simple operation of checking if string is empty or not.

Here's my simple layout:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click me"
        android:id="@+id/btnClick"/>
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Write something to print"
        android:id="@+id/edtTxt"/>
```

and with **MainActivity.kt** I've below stuff

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        btnClick.setOnClickListener {
            val message=edtTxt.text
            if (message == "")
                longToast("Come on! Write something")
            else
                longToast("You've written $message")
        }
    }
}
```

So initially I've written code within clicklistener as

```
val message=edtTxt.text
if (message.equals("")) //this here
    longToast("Come on! Write something")
else
    longToast("You've written $message")
```

Later on the IDE suggested to replace it with

[image: IDE Suggestion]

and I tried on doing that with `if (message=="")` but that started showing **Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'Editable!' and 'String' when comparing string** error. This is totally confusing.

My doubts here:

- What does this actually mean?
- How can I apply what IDE suggested or is there any workaround to get this done?

Comment: I don't know about Kotlin, but in Java, you have to convert `Editable` to String, eg `message.toString()`

Comment: @VassilisPallas Oh yea.. That's pretty much clear now.. `edtTxt.text` is just a replacement for java's `editTxt.getText()` so basically this has to be converted to string before using `==`. and yea error message makes sense now.. :) thank you for the clarification. Could you please add it as answer??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`edtTxt.text` is just a replacement for java's `editTxt.getText()`. So basically this has to be converted to `String` before using `==` operator.

If you want to get the String from the `Editable` object use `toString()` method.

```
val message=edtTxt.text.toString()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
btnClick.setOnClickListener {
    // edtTxt.text  type of EditText
    val message=edtTxt.text.toString() 
    if (message == "")
        longToast("Come on! Write something")
    else
        longToast("You've written $message")
}
```